# Import of a module in the same directory doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have a dir with the two modules *LoadFromData* and *WriteInData*. The first one calls the second one. I import the second one at the beginning and even the auto suggestion lists the function I want to call. As soon as I run the code I get an **ModuleNotFoundError**

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8h8B.png)

Module 1

```
import WriteInData as wd
[...]
def createNewFile(filePath: str) -> bool:
    #create pw file if not existent
    try:
        if wd.writeInitalData(filePath):
            print("The directory path {} was created".format(filePath))
            return True
    except FileExistsError:
        pass #writeLog
    else:
        return False
```

Module2:

```
def writeInitalData(filePath: str) -> bool:
    with open(filePath, 'w') as csvfile:
        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        filewriter.writerow(['id','name','description','password','created_on','last_modified_on'])
    return True
```

What I tried so far:

- rename the module
- call another function from the module
- call another module

None of this works. It seems the way I import is wrong, but I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong

Comment: The directory contains a "WriteInData.py" but no "WriteData.py".

Comment: Ahh sorry, in the screenshot it is already renamed. But the code is from before. I will just fix it to make it clear.

Comment: Which and where is the main script (the initially run script)?

Comment: It is outisde the Controller directory. Without the "WriteInData" call, it is working. So the main file calls the "LoadFromData" without any issues.

Comment: If the "Controller" directory is not listed in "sys.path", then the import should be relative, i. e. `from . import WriteInData as wd`. This may also require a `__init__.py` file in the "Controller" directory (file can be empty).

Comment: The solution was, that I have to add the full path from the src folder -> "src.main.Controller.WriteInData"

Answer (score 0):

The **solution** of my problem was to add the full directory path starting from src, although it is the same directory.
Therefore:

- Wrong: `import WriteInData`
- Right: `import src.main.Controller.WriteInData`